# Wrong answer for code to convert between Java camel case and C++ underscore identifiers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have been asked to write a program to detect which of the following formats are used for an identifier, and then to convert that identifier to the other format:

- In Java, a multiword identifier is constructed in the following manner: the first word is written starting from the small letter, and the following ones are written starting from the capital letter, no separators are used. All other letters are small. Examples of a Java identifier are `javaIdentifier`, `longAndMnemonicIdentifier`, `name`, `nEERC`.
- C++ uses only small letters in its identifiers. To separate words it uses the underscore character ‘_’. Examples of C++ identifiers are `c_identifier`, `long_and_mnemonic_identifier`, `name` (you see that when there is just one word Java and C++ people agree), `n_e_e_r_c`.

If it is neither, the program should report an error. Translation must preserve the order of words and must only change the case of letters and/or add/remove underscores.

Input:

The input file consists of several lines that contains an identifier. It consists of letters of the English alphabet and underscores. Its length does not exceed 100.

Output:

If the input identifier is Java identifier, output its C++ version. If it is C++ identifier, output its Java version. If it is none, output 'Error!' instead.

---

So here's my code in C++; I submitted it on the online judge but it gave the wrong answer. I have no idea what's wrong. It passed all my own test cases.

Can someone help me find the problem?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

void Convert(string input){
    string output = "";
    string flag = "";
    bool underscore = false;
    bool uppercase = false;
    if ( islower(input[0]) == false){
        cout << "Error!" <<endl;
        return;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < input.size(); i++){
        if ( (isalpha( input[i] ) || (input[i]) == '_') == false){
            cout << "Error!" <<endl;
            return;
        }
        if (islower(input[i])){
            if (underscore){
                underscore = false;
                output += toupper(input[i]);
            }
            else
                output += input[i];

        }
        else if (isupper(input[i])){
            if (flag == "C" || uppercase){
                cout << "Error!"<<endl;
                return;
            }
            flag = "Java";
            output += '_';
            output += tolower(input[i]);

        }
        else if (input[i] == '_'){
            if (flag == "Java" || underscore){
            cout << "Error!" <<endl;
            return;
            }
            flag = "C";
            underscore = true;
        }
    }
    cout << output <<endl;
} 

int main(){
    string input;
    while (cin >> input)
        Convert(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does the online judge show what input they used? (and what output your program give?)

Comment: nope...unfortunately..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if the last character is a `_`? In that case, you should probably also print return `Error!`.

Also, it looks like you're never changing `uppercase` - you should probably remove that.

Comment: also it does not support identifiers such as `a1`

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski That's not allowed though - `"It consists of letters of the English alphabet and underscores"` (no mention of numbers).

Comment: Dukeling: Thank you. But I don't think that's really going to matter, since in the whole program, uppercase is always going to be FALSE. (I never change it to TRUE)

Comment: @user3213711 Yeah, just noticed that. I edited my answer (speculating a bit).